# How to set a TCP server timeout when accepting multiple client connections

Tags: c, select, tcp, server, timeout

I am working on a function in my TCP server which accepts a predetermined number of client connections within a defined time period (I set it to 10 seconds for now) and returns when the predetermined number of connections has been reached. I am using the select function to make the server timeout, but for some reason the timeout resets each time a client joins. e.g if a client joins the server after 5 seconds then the timeout resets and starts counting down again from 10. Help would be very much appreciated, thanks.

I'm using mac and I think on this OS FD_ISSET is used to check whether a client has connected (which I am pretty sure is not needed on Linux). So you can just treat the return value of this function the way you would treat the return value of the select function on linux.

```c
while (num_conn < NO_OF_CLIENTS) {

    // Listen for clients
    err = listen(server_fd, 128);
    if (err < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not listen on socket\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Zero out memory for the client information
    memset( & client, 0, sizeof(client));

    socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client);
    FD_ZERO( & set);
    FD_SET(server_fd, & set);

    select(server_fd + 1, & set, NULL, NULL, & timeout);

    // server times out after allowing 30 seconds for clients to join.
    // If no clients join function returns 0. Otherwise returns no_clients
    nready = FD_ISSET(server_fd, & set);
    printf("nready is: %d\n", nready);

    if (nready == 0) {
        return num_conn; // returns number of connections if a time out occurs. 
    }

    // Accept the connection from the client
    client_fd[num_conn] = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr * ) & client, & client_len);
    if (client_fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not establish new connection\n");
        // SEND REJECT??
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Assign value to number of clients here and let it set after a time out
    // more work to  be done here
    printf("Accepted connection from client %d\n", num_conn);
    num_conn++;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear which OS you are using, but from [man select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html): *"On Linux, select() modifies timeout to reflect the amount of time not slept; __most other implementations do not do this__.  (POSIX.1 permits either behavior.)"*. It looks like you rely on a specific non-standard behavior which is not universally implemented.

Comment: I'm using mac and I think on this OS FD_ISSET is used to check whether a client has connected (which I am pretty sure is not needed on Linux). So you can just treat the return value of this function the way you would treat the return value of the select function on linux.

Comment: If you need to have timeouts for each socket separately, you need to have some kind of priority queue for them and choose the lowest timeout for `select`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> select(server_fd + 1, & set, NULL, NULL, & timeout);
> ```

Your code relies on select modifying the `timeout` you've set outside the loop, so that `timeout` reflects the remaining time. But you cannot rely on this behavior since it is specific to only some platforms like Linux.

Notably on your platform MacOS the [man page of select](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/select.2.html) clearly states that the timeout is not changed in the way you rely on:

> ... To effect a poll, the timeout argument should be
>        non-nil, pointing to a zero-valued timeval structure.  **Timeout is not
>        changed by select()**, and may be reused on subsequent calls, however it is
>        good style to re-initialize it before each invocation of select().

This means you have to figure out instead yourself the time spend in `select` and adjust the `timeout` accordingly when calling `select` again.